# HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 4

Tags: java

Cannot understand why index out of bounds. The usual case of where that happens does not seem to be the problem so im a little stuck. Please Help

```
@Override
@Transactional
public Boolean RegVali(User user){
        String hql = "from User";
        Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<User> listUser = (List<User>) query.list();
        int i=1;
        int j=listUser.size();
        for (Iterator<User> it = listUser.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            if(i>j){
                return true;
            }
            if(listUser.get(i).getEmail()==user.getEmail()){
                return false;
            }
            else{
                i++;
            }

    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The index to a `List`'s `get` operation should be 0 ≤ index < `listUser.size()`.

You're running from 1 through `listUser.size()`, `listUser.size()` is out of bounds.

As an aside - why use an iteration loop and get by index instead of using the iteration variable?

Answer (score 0):

You have an error because `i` is initialized to 1. The reason is that sequential structures in Java, like arrays and lists, are zero-indexed. Meaning, the first item is at position 0, second is at position 1... Therefore, What you should do is initialize `i` to 0, not 1.

***Explanation:***

Let's say you only have one item in `listUser`, then `i` and `j` before the loop will both be 1.

Therefore, inside your loop, the check

```
if(i>j){
    return true;
}
```

Will not be true since `i == j` or `1 == 1`. So your program will continue to the second `if` statement.

Now, in the second check:

```
if(listUser.get(i).getEmail()==user.getEmail()){
    return false;
}
```

you call:

```
listUser.get(i)
```

Since `i` is 1, and the list only has one item, that item is at position 0, not 1, so you are trying to access a value outside the range.

Also, assuming emails are `Strings`, you are comparing them using `==` operator which isn't correct. You should use `equals()` instead. [**`Here's why`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

Furthermore, your loop is more complicated than it needs to be. One way you can simplify it is with a [**`foreach`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) loop where you wouldn't need `i` or `j` and the code would be much cleaner:

```
public Boolean RegVali(User user){
    String hql = "from User";
    Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);

    List<User> listUser = (List<User>) query.list();
    for (User lUser : listUser) {
        if(lUser.getEmail().equals(user.getEmail())){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```